# Handling different JSON Request Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am working in a project where I need to send a request to remote service with 2 different formats

**Format 1:**

```
{
"templateId": "template1",
"configurationData": {
   "inboundHeaders": [
     {
      "key": "header1",
      "value": "value1"
     }, {
      "key": "header2",
      "value": "value2"
     }, {
      "key": "header3",
      "value": "value3"
     }
    ],
    "outboundHeaders": [
     {
      "key": "header4",
      "value": "value4"
     }, {
      "key": "header5",
      "value": "value5"
     }, {
      "key": "header6",
      "value": "value6"
     }
    ]
}
}
```

**Format 2**

```
{
    "templateId": "template1",
    "configurationData": {
           "inboundHeaders": "head1",
           "outboundHeaders" : "head2,head3"
        }
}
```

Now I have created one class

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "inboundHeaders", "outboundHeaders"})

public class ConfigurationData {

@JsonProperty("inboundHeaders")
private List<Header> inboundHeaders = null;

@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty("outboundHeaders")
private List<Header> outboundHeaders = null;

@JsonProperty("inboundHeaders")
private String inboundHeader = null;

@JsonProperty("outboundHeaders")
private String outboundHeader = null;

}
```

Getters and Setters would go here....

But when I am executing this program. Obviously, I am getting following exception like

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple fields representing property

How to handle these two different version (`java.util.List` vs `java.lang.String`) of requests in one `Json` POJO?

Comment: So do you really need to send them at the same time in the same request? So an example what kind of Json in the whole you need to have as request.

Comment: Not on the same request but on different requests. I have modified the question to make it more clearer.

Comment: So you still need to have a single POJO to serialize to JSON?

Comment: Yes, I want to as there are already so many classes been created and I don't want to create many for this thing as of now. And also this is one of the example of bunch of APIs where they have different structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options.

1. Create two classes and two methods to call remote service like:

**Lists**:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "inboundHeaders", "outboundHeaders"})
public class ConfigurationDataLists {
    @JsonProperty("inboundHeaders")
    private List<Header> inboundHeaders = null;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty("outboundHeaders")
    private List<Header> outboundHeaders = null;
}
```

**Strings**:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "inboundHeaders", "outboundHeaders"})
public class ConfigurationDataString {
    @JsonProperty("inboundHeaders")
    private String inboundHeader = null;

    @JsonProperty("outboundHeaders")
    private String outboundHeader = null;
}
```

2. Use Map

I will prefer option 1.

Comment: I liked your solution but @JsonProperty I would be setting in class having ConfigurationDataString or ConfigurationDataList?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from Francisco Pérez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606138/6413377) is absolutely correct but you later clarified your question. The possibilities to limit new classes are - well - limited. You either need to create a class representinng each different DTO or make some sort of manual serializing.

One thing you can do is that you create an interface for different types of configuration data DTOs, so just:

```
interface IConfigurationData {}
```

then you have *this template* create or change it so that `configurationData` is of type tha interface:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Template {
    private String templateId;
    private IConfigurationData configurationData;
}
```

Then using the DTO classes in above mentioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606138/6413377) let them implement this interface, like:

```
public class ConfigurationDataLists implements IConfigurationData {...}
```

and

```
public class ConfigurationDataString implements IConfigurationData {...}
```

Then you will be able to do two different queries like this:

```
Template template1 = new Template();
template1.setTemplateId("1");
template1.setConfigurationData(new ConfigurationDataLists());

Template template2 = new Template();
template2.setTemplateId("2");
template2.setConfigurationData(new ConfigurationDataString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same name to different properties like you did. E.g. - inboundHeaders.

You have to change one of the propertyname. In simple words you have to keep the 
**@JsonProperty** 
unique.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I understand but don't we have any way to switch it on during runtime.

Comment: No, it creates ambiguity. So I guess no option to distinguish at runtime.